# Insert specific number of records with same column value into a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have two tables, `tblProducts` and `tblPromoItems`, that will both contain the same record types. For simplification sake, suppose each record only has two attributes, `ID` and `creation_date`. How would I take records from `tblProducts` and insert into `tblPromoItems`, such that only *n* total records are inserted and there are only *i* instances of records with the same `creation_date`?

For example, using the below table how would I insert a total of 3 records, given the condition that there can be at most 2 records with the same `creation_date`.

```
tblProducts

ID| creation_date

A | 2014-12-01

B | 2014-12-01

C | 2014-12-01

D | 2014-12-02
```

Comment: Which `RDBMS` and what defines which 2 records to return?

Comment: you'll have to come up with criteria to determine the winner when there are multiple possibilities

Comment: Guess I tried to simplify it too much. This will be for ms sql server. And in reality the creation_date field would be a datetime, so I can tell what was actually "first" for a given date (and that will be used as the tie breaker). I am just trying to find a good way to start out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with a `common table expression` to get 2 records per date:

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by cast(creation_date as date) 
                       order by creation_date desc) rn
  from tblProducts
  )
select * 
from cte
where rn <= 2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14ac5/3)

I'm not quite sure what you mean by only n total records can be inserted.  Presumably you want to limit the number of inserts into the table?  One way is to use `top` for that -- `select top 100 ...`

Comment: Thanks. I got moved off to something else and just now came back to this SQL. Hadn't used the ROW_NUMBER() before, and it worked like a charm. I would give you an upvote, but I don't have the reputation to do so.